# python 3.6 how does __str__ affect print()

Tags: python-3.x, string, printing

I have defined a class foo and a function `foo.__str__()`. If x is an instance of foo, `x.__str__()` returns a string representation of x. I have checked this on examples and it seems to work as I wish it to.

My question is, how to I now define `foo.print()`. Am I supposed to use `__str__` or, annoyingly, repeat the code of `__str__`?

Comment: you dont. you simply `print( your_class_instance )`

Comment: also: override `__repl__` - it is used if you do `print( [i1,i2,i3,i4]) ` multiple instances of your class inside a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `print` just calls `__str__`, so you dont need to do anything else. You probably will also need to define `__repr__`, which returns the *representation* of the object

### Code

```python
class A:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'in __str__'

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'in __repr__'

a = A()

print(a) # __str__
print([a]) # __repr__
```

### Output

[image]

Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr) about `__str__` vs `__repr__`

Comment: But when I did x.print() I got an error message saying that x had no method print

Comment: you `print(object)`  .. not `object.print()` - see my comment wich tells you about the same as this answer

Comment: @DavidEpstein Why are you trying to call `print` as though it's a method of the class?